# flutter: ">=0.2.4 <2.0.0" pub get failed (65) when cloud_firestore package is used in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I tried to add the google_sign_in,flutter_auth and cloud_firestore it is throwing me the error that flutter: ">=0.2.4 <2.0.0".I  tried to run flutter dector -v the output is

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /home/ramu/Downloads/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (4 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/ramu/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/ramu/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/73/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/73/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.0.2

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your environment sdk in `pubspec.yaml` from `>=0.2.4 <2.0.0` to `>=2.1.0 <3.0.0`

The upper bound for your environment sdk is below version 2.0.0 but [google_sign_in](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/7c72953b0991be2252e42d8dda520d66dcbc5cee/packages/google_sign_in/pubspec.yaml#L25) ,[firebase_auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/7c72953b0991be2252e42d8dda520d66dcbc5cee/packages/firebase_auth/pubspec.yaml#L33), and [cloud_firestore](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/7c72953b0991be2252e42d8dda520d66dcbc5cee/packages/cloud_firestore/pubspec.yaml#L29) requires at least `>=2.0.0-dev.28.0` (which is newer then what you have specified for your project).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete that project folder and create a new one and paste all the code in the newly created project.